# regex expression to replace a string

Tags: regex

I need to replace any characters in the set...

```
[]*?/\:
```

with an empty string.  Can someone post how this is done?

Comment: btw, I am using C# Regex object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C#

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"[\[\\\]*?/:]", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the language you are using; but you could use (with sed)

```
sed -e "s/\[\]\*\?\/\\\://g" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl: $str =~ s/.//g;

But I think you mean replacement with a Space: $str =~ s/./ /g;

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript

```
var s = "he[ll]o? \*/ foo:bar";
var replaced = s.replace(/[[\\\]*?/:]/g, "");

?replaced
>>hello  foobar
```